Is there a shortcut in Overleaf to switch among files in the same folder?
I am writing my thesis using Overleaf from Google Chrome in a Windows laptop. I have divided it in several files (some .tex files for the different chapters and a .bib for the references). I would like to switch between the different files without using the mouse. Something similar to CTRL+Shift for Chrome tabs and Alt+Shift for apps in Windows. Is there such a shortcut?
Excuse me if the question has already been posed. I couldn't find it by searching "[Overleaf] shortcuts". Additionally, pressing F1 gets me to Chrome help rather than Overleaf help, so I couldn't use that either.
Thanks!

Welcome. // Perhaps this gives you an idea? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603149/custom-hotkeys-on-overleaf // Try also searching this site, e.g.also  via tags.

Hi, I don't think that solves my issue. I've searched some more, but I still haven't been able to find the answer.

you can open each file in a separate chrome tab and use chrome to switch

Oh yeah, I hadn't thought of that. It'd still be nicer if there was a way to do it without opening new tabs, but that works.
